# MySQL - Java - Execute with a defined Method - Statements

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Ahh I don't know how to ask that question xD

I have a java Project and want to predefine Statements like new DB Table, Insert, Delete, etc.

I have predefined methods, but the ResultSets close and i get the Error:

```
Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

I googled and found out, that for each statement there is only one ResultSet allowed, and the last one is closed if another one is opened. I got that much, but how should I define the method then?

RN i have a Method connect(), that connects to the database and creates a statement for that connection.
then I have a method called newEntry(), that uses this statement. But method deleteEntry() also uses that statement. As 3 other methods.

Also some background information: Due to multiple Treads it can happen, that one Method can be called multiple times at one specific point.

How to solve this?

Well...thank you for your help :)

**EDIT:**

```
public static ResultSet getEntrys(String fields, String name, String where) {
        String sql = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM " + name + " WHERE " + where;

        try {
            return resultStmt.executeQuery(sql);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Then somewhere else in another class I call this Method like:

```
ResultSet set = MySQL.getEntrys("*", 
                    "Stats_Channels", 
                    "guild_ID = " + guild.getIdLong());


try {
    if(!set.next()) {

                //Do something

        MySQL.newEntry("Stats_Channels", 
                    "guild_ID, category_ID", 
                    guild.getIdLong() + ", " + category.getIdLong());

                //Do something

    }
    else {
        long categoryid = set.getLong("category_ID"); //-> Here it says ResultSet is Closed

                //Do something
                        }
                    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. This exception indicates that the result set is closed when you try to access it. We can't tell you the specific reason when you don't show us what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long and also sorry for not really providing a minimal reproducible example...

Comment: It is not a [mre], because it is missing `MySQL`, and if `MySQL` is something that is shared between threads, then the problem might be that one thread performed an action  that closed the result set (eg executing a query on the same `Statement`) between the execution and retrieval from the result.

Comment: MySQL is the class where al the functions like connect(), disconnect() and newEntry(), etc. are.

But how should I solve it then?

Comment: Don't share connections, statements, etc between threads. Make sure each thread uses their own connection.

Comment: Like a new Instance of the class?
With a own connection?

Comment: Yes. The alternative is to use synchronization or another form of mutual exclusion to make sure threads don't interfere with each other, but that is a lot harder to do correctly (and depending on the type of processing, the overhead and waiting between threads would then probably be better and simpler to go to single-threaded processing).

Comment: Is there a way I can chat with you? Have a few more Qestions and I'm stuck rn :/
If not also ok^^

Comment: Unfortunately no. You could post a new question, and maybe if I have time I'll look at, or someone else will.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway^^